# F# less than operator in pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

For some reason the less than operator in this pattern match will not work. It's the only error I have and it's driving me insane.
I'm probably missing something really obvious but all help is appreciated.

```
let CheckAccount account = 
match account with
| {Balance < 10.00} -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is Low")
| {Balance >= 10.00 and <= 100.00} -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is OK")
| {Balance > 100.00} -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is High")
```

This is the type:

```
type Account = {AccountNumber:string 
            mutable Balance:float} 
            member this.Withdraw(amnt:float) = 
                if amnt > this.Balance then
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to withdraw. The Amount you wish to withdraw is greater than your current balance.")
                else
                    this.Balance <- this.Balance - amnt
                    Console.WriteLine("You have withdrawn £" + amnt.ToString() + ". Your balance is now: £" + this.Balance.ToString())
            member this.Deposit(amnt:float) =
                this.Balance <- this.Balance + amnt
                Console.WriteLine("£" + amnt.ToString() + " Deposited. Your new Balance is: £" + this.Balance.ToString())
            member this.Print = 
                Console.WriteLine("Account Number: " + this.AccountNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Balance: £" + this.Balance.ToString())
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use pattern matching to extract the balance value, bind it to a new name and then compare the values using the `when` clause:

```
let CheckAccount account = 
  match account with
  | {Balance = b} when b < 10.00 -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is Low")
  | {Balance = b} when b >= 10.00 && b <= 100.00 -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is OK")
  | {Balance = b} when b > 100.00 -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is High")
```

I would say that in this case, you are not actually getting much from using pattern matching. If you wrote the same code using `if`, then it would probably look nicer.

You can use a bit fancier approach and define active patterns that let you compare values:

```
let (|LessThan|_|) k value = if value < k then Some() else None
let (|MoreThan|_|) k value = if value > k then Some() else None
```

Then you can use those instead:

```
let CheckAccount account = 
  match account with
  | {Balance = LessThan 10.0} -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is Low")
  | {Balance = LessThan 100.0 & MoreThan 10.0 } -> Console.WriteLine("Balance is OK")
```

This is actually fairly interesting - because you can use the `&` construct to combine multiple active patterns as in `LessThan 100.0 & MoreThan 10.0`.

Comment: I got distracted in the middle of writing this answer :-) Added one more thing with active patterns!

Comment: While the provided answer here solves the problem, I am still left wondering why < doesn't work. What is the reason? Any insights would be a really valuable addition to this answer imo. Thanks!